# Spring cloud composed task event

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I'm after the composed task execution listener, that publishes events to middle-ware, basically, the same behavior as documented for custom task [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#stream-integration-events)

Is there any way to enable this feature for composed tasks run via SCDF REST API ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean is there a way to add the batch events to a composed task?

Comment: Yes, I need to get events about start and end of the composed task